# how to validate user phone number in textinput?

Tags: javascript, react-native, validation

I have a `textinput` and i want to validate user input before it's showing on `textinput`.

i have tried used regex to do this, but i have a problem with the following code:

```
  _onChangeHP(hp){
    console.log('hp', hp)
    let reg = /^08[0-9]{9,}$/
    if(reg.test(hp)){
      this.setState({noHP:hp})
    }
  }

  <TextInput
    value={this.state.noHP}
    maxLength={13}
    placeholder={'08xxxxxxxxx'}
    keyboardType="numeric"
    onChangeText={(text)=>this._onChangeHP(text)}
  />
```

`_onChangeHP()` function checked one by one, so `regex pattern` never pass true in `if statement`,

is there a way to validate user input?

My Expected result is `setState` when user value first string is `0` and 2nd string is `8` and the rest is numeric only,

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern function where number can be put in conditional.

```
<input  maxLength={13} placeholder='08xxxxxxxxx' keyboardType="numeric"
      pattern="[0][8][0-9]{11}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with only one regex

```js
_onChangeHP('08')
_onChangeHP('01')
_onChangeHP('08222222')
function _onChangeHP(hp){
        let regStartsWith = new RegExp('^08', 'i');
        let regAfter =  /^\d+$/;
        if(regStartsWith.test(hp)){ // this will check if starts with 08
          if(regAfter.test(hp.substring(2))){
             console.log(true) // this will check if hp has number after 08
             return true;
          }
          else{
            console.log(false);
            return false;
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log(false);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: because of my issue is on `textinput` i need to check one by one every string, when user type 0, and check `_onChangeHP()` it would never go into `if statement` in other word, textinput will return false forever